# HOK React memo, он сравнивает пропы. А если компонент не принимает пропы, будет отдаваться одна и та же ссылка? Это также оптимизация?

Tags: reactjs

Подскажите такую ситуацию, есть родитель который часто перерендываеться, в нем есть ребенок который не принимает пропы, если я оберну ребенка в React.memo это же будет оптимизация? Я правильно понимаю? (В доках в основном написано только о сравнении пропов)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это будет оптимизацией, так можно делать

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос